# Add to ActivityHistory of specific opportunity using APEX

Tags: apex, opportunity, activities, activityhistory

I want to add an `ActivityHistory` to a specific opportunity. I'm just confused on how to do it to a specific opportunity. Initially, I thought it was w/the `WhatId` but that's not working. This is what I have :

```
ActivityHistory newAH = new ActivityHistory();
newAH.WhatId = '1234566'; //In my code, its an Opp Id
```

The error I'm getting is `Field is not writeable: ActivityHistory.WhatId`

If this isn't the right way to insert an `ActivityHistory` what is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActivityHistory` is a read-only object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm).

> ### ActivityHistory
>
> This read-only object is displayed in a related list of closed activities—past events and closed tasks—related to an object. It includes activities for all contacts related to the object. ActivityHistory fields for phone calls are only available if your organization uses Salesforce CRM Call Center.
>
> #### Supported Calls
>
> `describeSObjects()`

Comment: Just to clarify, what this is saying is that if I make an `Event` or `Task` and is set to closed, it will automatically save it into the related list of an `ActivityHistory`? Right?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly how you would create them. I saw some talk of needing `SeeAllData` to see the resulting records, but I have not confirmed. I would try it without first, and only toggle it on for specific `testMethod`s if you aren't seeing the records created.

Comment: That also means, for example, if I migrate all my `Events and Tasks` from one opportunity to another...it will move all of the ones that are closed automatically to the `ActivityHistory`, right?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that one. Sounds like a separate (and possibly more interesting) question!

Comment: Let me try it out! From my understanding, it should work but I'll let you know :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: If an event or task is closed, it will automatically get moved to the `Activity History` related list. The way to migrate only closed `events and tasks` is to filter it out by `status for tasks' and `end date for events' (you would need to compare dates)